# Libreoffice's insert special character window looks HUGE (can't resize to smaller)

Tags: libreoffice, window-management

I write this post because I have the doubt about this being a libreoffice bug, a GNOME bug... or what could be the cause, because I don't seem to find and issue related to this anywhere else.

When I go to Libreoffice Insert > special characters menu, the window that opens with the characters, is huge and doesn't fit on the screen, so I can't really use it.

[image]

I used to be in Debian 10 (since it came out up until 2 months ago) and now I'm in Debian testing. Back in the day I had installed the flatpak version (so, the *"fresh"* version; the last one I had was v. 7.1, I believe) of libreoffice and had the same issue. I thought back then that the problem might be due to using a flatpak (sometimes they don't integrate well with system themes... etc).

But now I've realized that I have the same problem with the official repos from Debian bullseye: I'm running LibreOffice 7.0.4.2. Having the same problem in different number versions... and both flatpak and regular repo packages... makes me thing the problem should be something different.

I'm now running GNOME 3.38.4. Back in the day, GNOME 3.30 in Debian stable.

I can make the window a bit bigger, but I cant make it smaller! It's twice my desktop resolution (1440p) in high, so it is impossible for me to reach the INSERT button... lol! I rarely use this option, but when I need it... I end up searching for the character online and copy&pasting... which doesn't seem ok.

Anyone else has this problem? Do you guys have any idea what should I try?

EDIT: I searched about how to report a bug in libreoffice, but I've never used bugzilla, so I thought I should ask first.

Comment: Poked around in LO Writer options on my system to see if I could reproduce the problem. Changing icon style in `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View` from `Automatic (Tango)` to `Elementary (SVG)` (which I picked at random) caused the effect you're experiencing. Changing back to Tango returned the Special Characters dialog to normal after restarting Writer. Further changes to icon style, regardless of style selected, had no effect on the Special Characters dialog. System info: Fedora 32 \w Xfce and LO 6.4.7.2 installed from repo.

Comment: @DavidYockey that is VERY much appreciated. I don't have the same icon packs, but I do use an SVG icon pack (and I remember using that also on back en Debian stable in flatpak version). As you suggested, changing the icon pack, seems to solve the problem, even if I pick the SVG back. THANK YOU very much.

Do you know how should I report this to libreoffice?

Comment: Glad it helped. On reporting it to LO, probably best to take a look at their page on [how to report bugs in LibreOffice](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport). From a quick glance, it looks like you'll need to create a Bugzilla account on their site.